# Java Eclipse Git team-->(sub menu for git) lost

Tags: eclipse

I am new to JAVA Eclipse and while working with my workspace, i had to delete everything and recreate my workspace from GIT. Now i was able to download the latest code and its compiling but i lost the sub items for the team menu which show up when you right click on project workspace in package explorer.

Please note Git perspective is working fine as shown here in figure.

Git Pespective **WORKS FINE**....But packageExplorer-Team-menu **NOT WORKING**
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK i figured it out. I lost this menu because i imported my project into my workspace using File-->Import-->Maven--> Existing Maven Project.

When i tried following, Team menu started showing up.

Import--->Git---->Project from Git.  ( specify the git repository and import your project )

Now i can see Team--> all git menu options.

Importing the same project using git perspective did't solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please verify that the path of your working copy is the same than the path of your project in package explorer view. Maybe it's not the same folder.

Comment: I am pretty sure this is not the reason because my workspace folder and the folder where i have my source code was always different and the menu was working earlier. It just i have to delete my workspace and start from fresh and then i lost that menu option.

Comment: I think, I'm not clear. In fact, on my laptop, workspace folder and source folder are different.
But when I do a right click on my project in the package explorer view and when choose Properties. I can see the path of my project. In fact I guess you did a copy of your source code when you import your project. 

Anyway. Can you try this ? 
 - Create a new workspace
 - In Git perspective, add your Git repository

Comment: Sorry for the previous comment.

Can you try this ? 
 - Create a new workspace
 - In Git perspective, add your Git repository
 - On the node "Working directory", right click > "Copy path..."
 - On package explorer view, right click > Import > Maven Existing project
 - Paste the path and follow the wizard.
Tell me if it is OK.

Comment: I tried that. From Git perspective, Importing existing git repository / directory using Git url did't work. I still don't see that menu.